# Homology of spherical $3$-manifold group

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, cw-complexes

I have been studying $3$-manifolds recently and I got stuck in the following situation. For lens spaces the below fact is true.

Let $G$ be a finite group acting freely and orthogonally on $S^3$ so that $S^3/G$ is a spherical $ 3$ manifold. Now construct $K(G,1)$ whose CW structure has a $3$rd skeleton $X^3$ as $S^3/G$. Can I say that the attaching map in the cellular chain $H_4(X^4, X^3) \to H_3(X^3, X^2)$ is zero? I want to show that $H_3(G; \mathbb{Z})\neq 0$.

Any reference will be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that the third homology is $\mathbb Z$ in the $S^3/G$ orientable case?

Comment: @WillSawin: there are no non-orientable spherical 3-manifolds.

Comment: I don't think it's true for lens spaces.  $\pi_3 \mathbb{R}P^3$ is the integers, but  $\pi_3 \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ is trivial, similarly, $H_3 \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ is $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 6):

The attaching map has to kill $\pi_3(S^3/G)$, and the map $\mathbb Z =\pi_3(S^3) \to \pi_3 (S^3/G) $ induced by the covering is an isomorphism, so $\pi_3$ is generated by the class of the covering 3-sphere. The attaching map will attach a single 4-cell with boundary the covering 3-sphere.

The induced homology class is the fundamental class of the covering 3-sphere, which is $|G|$ times the generator of $H_3(S_3/G)$.

So I think the map you want is not $0$ but rather is multiplication by $|G|$.